# Item in ListBox can have different value in textbox?

Tags: c#

I have this ListBox that displays items I dragged from my DataGridView. Items in ListBox displays their `MenuCode`. What I want to happen is I want to show the `MenuPrice` of each item I have on ListBox on a TextBox. I tried to do this but the `MenuCode` displays on that TextBox. Please see the image below.

[image]

Is it possible to have the `MenuPrice` displayed on that TextBox? I have done this code but I dont think this is right.

```
private void menuDataGrid_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) //this code triggers when I dragged an item from datagridview to listbox.
{
    menuDataGrid.DoDragDrop(menuDataGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString(), DragDropEffects.Copy);
}

private void menuListBox_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //this is the code when I select an item on the listview, then appears at the textbox
{        
    pricetxtbox.Text = menuListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
}

private void ShowDataToGrid()  //datagrid code
{
    db_connection();

    MySqlDataAdapter datagrid = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    string selectAll = "SELECT * FROM Menu";
    datagrid.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(selectAll, connect);

    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    datagrid.Fill(tbl);

    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = tbl;

    menuDataGrid.DataSource = bs;
    menuDataGrid.Columns[6].Visible = false;
    menuDataGrid.Columns[7].Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the GridView's code?

Comment: Hi @MohamedNajiullah I will edit my post. :)

Comment: I'm sorry. I wasn't clear enough. I meant the GridView's aspx code

Comment: @MohamedNajiullah this is C# windows form application. :)

Comment: My bad. Is the MenuPrice present on the GridView as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the MenuPrice is also present on the GridView at a different cell, say `Cells[4]`.

Then you can do something like this

```
private void menuListBox_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //this is the code when I select an item on the listview, then appears at the textbox
{        
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in menuDataGrid.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[3].Value.ToString().Equals(menuListBox.SelectedItem.ToString()))
        {
            pricetxtbox.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: glad to hear that!

Answer (score 1):

You should pack your data into an object class with properties you want to display and hold. For example:

```
public class MenuItem()
{
    public float MenuPrice { get; set; }
    public string MenuCode { get; set; }
}
```

If you store data of type MenuItem in your ListView, you will be able to do:

```
private void menuListBox_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) textbox
{        
    var item = menu.ListBoxItem.SelectedItem as MenuItem;
    if(item == null) return;

    pricetxtbox.Text = item.MenuPrice;
}
```

This would be one way to do it, if you want to enhance your code you should probably consider using databinding for you textboxes.